# Different behaviour from PHP 7.3>7.4 with loading abstract classes and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

When I use PHP 7.3 and the following code, everything works as expected.

```
// bootstrap.php
function load($class, $dir) {
  foreach ( scandir( $dir ) as $file ) {
    if (startsWith($file,".")) continue;
    if (is_dir($dir."/".$file)) {
      load($class,$dir."/".$file);
    } else {
      if (startsWith($file, $class)) {
        require_once $dir."/".$file;
      }
    }
  }
}

function autoloadsystem($class){
  load($class, 'libs');
}

spl_autoload_register("autoloadsystem");
```

And

```
// AbstractClass.php
abstract class AbstractClass {
  // ...
}
```

And

```
// MyClass.php
class MyClass extends AbstractClass {
  // ..
}
```

And

```
// index.php
<?php
require 'bootstrap.php';
$class = new MyClass();
```

Then I switched by mistake to PHP 7.4 on one maschine (MacOS, brew, php 7.4.3) and now I have problems with the autoload system. The given autoload will not recognize the AbstractClass and throws errors. There is no "second" call to `autoloadsystem` with `"AbstractClass"`. I could not find any changes in the Changelog of PHP 7.4 about `spl_autoload_register` (https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration74.php).

It looks to me, as of parsing the file in `require_once` is not using the "global `spl_autoload_register`'d function and so does not recursive load classes. I can see the same behaviour for interface definitions. If a class is implementing an interface, PHP 7.4 breaks with an unknown interface definition.

Is this a known issue? I could not find anything about that on Google or PHP. Is there a workoround (except manually require all abstract classes interfaces or -of course- switching back to 7.3)?

Comment: could you please give me exact error statement ?

Comment: The error is: `Error: Class AbstractClass not found.` It is thrown in the line `class MyClass extends AbtrastClass`. If I add a debug message in the `autoloadsystem` function I can not see, that it is called with the parameter `$class=AbstractClass` at all.